# Copy text from sheets of a workbook into destination sheet under

Tags: vba

I have two sheets

1. sheet1 has this text:

   ```
   vdom "name"
   ip address x.x.x.x subnet 255.255.255.255
   vlan id xxx
   ...
   ...
   ```
2. sheet2 has the customers table:
   each row contains all information of the customer

   - on colume A I have all of the vdom names "name"
   - on colume B I have all of the "vlan ids" number
   - on colume C I have all of the ip addresses

I want the vba script to search in sheet1 and find the name matches in sheet2
and then copy the details(vlan,ip,..) to sheet1 instead of the original details.

Comment: The ip address is row below the name

Comment: Also the vlan id is row below the ip

Comment: I do not understand how is it organized.
You have all the info in one cell in sheet 1?

Comment: the task seems far to easy.. so I guess it must be something more to it

Comment: And `VLookUp` doesn't work? What VBA code are you currently using?

Comment: Yes all the info is in one cell in sheet 1

Comment: Please paste the code for it

Comment: Is this x.x.x.x to indicate the string layout, is it of fixed length, and this is what you want to overwrite? E.g with second string: so you might have vlan id xxx and this becomes vlan id 123?

Comment: Is the example text in one cell or multiple rows? The comments seem to suggest both when it should be one or the other

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you could just record a macro for this?

i.e go on the developer tab in excel, click record macro and then just do what it is you want to do!

to make sure you have the developer tab follow **File->options->customize ribbon** and make sure you have developer ticked in the right hand side column!